# Angular GitHub Pages deploy net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: angular, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my Angular app to GitHub pages. For the most part, I've been following the instructions in the following article (section on GitHub Pages):

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

For the first couple of deployments, things worked fine. With the latest deployment, the app (in the GitHub Pages site) stopped working. And by "stopped working", I am referring to getting the following console output when I load the site (https://byannalam.github.io/savings-calulator/).
[image]

I would like to note that the above clipping was taken about an hour after I pushed the offending batch of commits to GitHub.

#### Other details

Angular CLI 9.0.5

GitHub repository: https://github.com/byannalam/savings-calulator

GitHub output folder is set to `master branch/docs`.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "savings-calculator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /savings-calculator/",
    "watch": "ng build --watch",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Is there anything that I could've done that might have broken it?

Comment: what is your command to publish? do you include 'baseHref' and 'deployUrl'?

Comment: I don't use a command to publish. What I've been doing is

1) running `npm run build-prod` (command definition is listed in package.json)
2) adding the generated files to a new commit
3) pushing everything to the master branch

Comment: I would like to add that before I settled on this approach, I tried several others. This was the only one that actually worked until today (even if I had to wait 20-ish minutes for the changes to show up in the site).

Comment: if you plan on access via a virtual folder you'll need to specify that in the build options: `npm run build-prod -- --deployUrl /savings_calulator/ --baseHref /saving_calulator/`   I'm not sure how it was working before

Comment: No such luck. Still giving me the same errors as in the screen clipping.